# Configure redirect asp.net/iis7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a website that opens when the user enters either http://example.com or http://www.example.com.

I need to configure the server or the app to redirect with a permanent redirect to www.example.com when example.com is accessed.

What is very important is that the path is preserved, so if example.com/path/page.aspx?p=1, the redirect should be done to www.example.com/path/page.aspx?p=1.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) you can do this by adding a configuration in you web.config. You need to install this module in your IIS as well. Here is an example, not fully tested:

```
<system.webserver>
<rewrite>
        <rules>               
            <rule name="Redirecting" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP}" pattern="^(http://)?example.com" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webserver>
```

Comment: doesn't work, but thanks anyway! I'll try to figure out how to preserve the protocol.. thanks!

Comment: It was just an example. Maybe this link can help you to understand better: [10 URL Rewriting Tips and Tricks](http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/)

Answer (score 1):

The [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) should do exactly what you need.